# How to set cache control header in Jersy response

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, jersey

I want to set the cache control header in Jersy response object.

I tried similar to it but didnot work.

The cache control still shows no cache in response.

```
 CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
        cc.setNoStore(true);
        cc.setNoCache(true);
        cc.setMustRevalidate(true);

   return Response.ok(pdf).cacheControl(cc).header("Pragma", "no-cache").build()
```

;

Resposne still shows cache control

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

Can some one tell how do we do that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it should be like this:

```
CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
cc.setNoCache(true);
cc.setNoStore(true);
cc.setMustRevalidate(true);
return Response.ok(pdf).cacheControl(cc).build();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have done the same right. Not sure why it is not getting updated still. Can you tell